# Manipulating a toy to play or run different contents already installed in it

Tags: microcontroller

If i had a toy like a car for example and it has a speaker that play a certain song once i switch on the car, how is it possible to reprogram it to play another song? How to know what kind of a micro-controller board it has, what is the language used to reprogram it or even finding source code for it?

Thanks for the clarification in advance!

Comment: you take it apart, examine the chips, look them up online, and most likely even if you find a recognizable part you probably cant reprogram it...but you might get lucky.  How were you thinking of doing it and what did you try?

Comment: Yet, reverse engineering is often more work that doing it from scratch your own way!